# HTML Email Spacing, CKEditor & PHPMail

Tags: html, ckeditor, phpmailer

I'm using CKEditor with Phpmail to send HTML emails. When I edit the email before sending it displays correctly, but when recipient receives the email it seems to have included extra spacing in the mail. I have included example screenshots and coding below, any ideas how I can solve this?

Email source:

```
<p style="margin-left:0cm; margin-right:0cm; text-align:left"><span style="color:#1F497D; font-family:calibri,sans-serif; font-size:11.0pt">Dear ,</span></p>

<p style="margin-left:0cm; margin-right:0cm; text-align:left"><span style="color:#1F497D; font-family:calibri,sans-serif; font-size:11.0pt">Kind regards,</span><br />
<br />
<strong><span style="color:#00B0F0; font-size:14.0pt">First&amp;Last Names</span></strong><br />
<strong><span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:11.0pt">Company Name</span></strong><br />
<span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:11.0pt">Direct:</span><span style="color:navy"> </span><span style="color:#E36C0A; font-size:11.0pt">0203 123&nbsp;<strong>4567</strong></span><br />
<span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:11.0pt">Email:</span><span style="color:navy"> </span><span style="color:blue; font-size:11.0pt"><a href="mailto:email@mail.com">e</a>mail@email.com</span><br />
<span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:11.0pt">Web:</span><span style="color:navy"> </span><span style="color:blue; font-size:11.0pt"><a href="http://mail.com">e</a>mail.com</span></p>

<p style="margin-left:0cm; margin-right:0cm; text-align:start"><span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:10.0pt">These terms apply.</span></p>

<p><span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:10.0pt">Confidentiality Notice: The information contained in this message and any attachment(s) may be confidential. You are hereby notified that any dissemination, distribution, copying, or use of or reliance upon the information contained in and transmitted with this message by or to anyone other than the recipient designated above by the sender is unauthorised and is strictly prohibited. For our joint protection, telephone calls may be recorded and/or monitored</span></p>

<p><span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:10.0pt">Company is registered in England - Company Number 123456</span></p>

<p><span style="color:#1F497D; font-size:10.0pt">Registered Office &ndash; London</span></p>
```

Email in CKEditor

[image: Email in CKEditor]

How email displays in Client

[image: How email displays in Client]

I have viewed the email across different devices been seem to have same issue. Also, I removed the LinkedIn image in first image, to save confusion :)

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the resulting HTML and see where the changes in style are coming from. Bear in mind that HTML rendering across email clients varies enormously, and is extremely idiosyncratic.

Comment: I noticed email is adding two extra <br> into the email, and also it's not liking special characters, for example bullet points is showing as â€¢

Comment: PHPMailer only touches `Body` content if you are using `msgHTML`, which is entirely optional. If you have character encoding problems, you probably need to set `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` and ensure that your whole workflow is UTF-8-safe.